# Can I use this garage door circuit to power an ESP8266

Tags: circuit-analysis, esp8266

So this circuit is from my garage door opener. Basically it has 24VDC coming into it which runs directly back to the motor unit of the garage door opener. My limited understanding says that there is an IC in the motor unit that senses the short or short running through the caps (ie build up time). My question is: can I put an arduino in parallel to this circuit without screwing up the sensing, and will the arduino still function when one of those circuits is closed?

[image: Circuit]
[image: Craftsman premium control console]
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: @Finbarr The aim is to make the entire thing controllable by the ESP8266. Use optocouplers in parallel with the switches. I could always run a 5/3.3v source to the IC but if I can tap it onto this somehow I would prefer that.

Comment: It will help to imagine what the other side looks like. Maybe a fixed voltage on the left, and the input on the right with a pull-down.

Comment: It's clearly not much of a DC supply as it's happy to be shorted indefinitely by the Garage Door button. You could connect an ammeter in series to see how much current flows when that button is pressed, which would give you an idea how much you can "siphon off" for your Arduino - but I suspect it won't be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I put an arduino in parallel to this circuit without screwing up the sensing?

No. This circuit does not supply continuous DC power -- whatever it's doing to sense the buttons with capacitors would necessarily involve sending an intermittent signal of some sort. The decoupling capacitors present on the Arduino board might allow it to "ride through" the interruptions, but would interfere with this sensing.

Comment: Yea that's what I thought